# Destructing transitivity hypothesis on simple predicate logic

Tags: coq

I'm new to Coq and am working on some exercises with predicate logic. In one of the exercises, a transitivity hypothesis is defined as follows:

```
Hypothesis Transitive : forall x, forall y, forall z, R x y /\ R y z -> R x z.
```

I have derived the following:

```
R : D -> D -> Prop
a, b, c : D
Hab : R a b
Hbc : R b c
```

My goal is to derive `Hac : R a c` as a hypothesis using Transitive. Seeing as I am new to Coq, I just tried some things I had seen before such as `destruct (Transitive a b c).` but this would result in the error `Not an inductive product`. So I figured I was supposed to provide `Hab and Hbc` as well and tried `destruct (Transitive a b c Hab Hbc).` which results in the following error: `The term "Hab" has type "R a b" while it is expected to have type "R a b /\ R b c".`. Okay, so I need to derive something of the type `R a b /\ R b c` first:

```
assert (R a b /\ R b c).
split.
exact Hab.
exact Hbc.
```

This indeed gives me an hypothesis `H0 : R a b /\ R b c` of the correct type. When filling this in, `destruct (Transitive a b c H0).` provides me with the error `Not an inductive product.` again. I have searched for quite a bit but haven't been able to find any decent explanation of this error.

What exactly does this error tell me? Why did the other error tell me that something of type `R a b /\ R b c` was required, but evaluation fails when this type is provided, again giving me this cryptic error about an inductive product? I'm looking for a bare bones Coq explanation and maybe solution, so no external packages. Note that I'm not looking to use or alter the target of the proof at all.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to misunderstand what `destruct` is for. `destruct` takes a term whose product is an inductive type, and performs case analysis. For example, if you have the hypothesis `H : A /\ B`, `destruct H as [HA HB].` gives you two hypotheses `HA : A` and `HB : B`. If you have `H : A \/ B`, `destruct H as [HA | HB]` (note the pipe, to separate the cases) splits the proof into two subproofs, one where you have `HA : A` and one where you have `HB : B`.

If you have already understood the basics of the underlying theory behind Coq, `destruct` just corresponds to pattern matching in Gallina.

In this case, `Transitive a b c H0` has type `R x z`. Since `R x z` is a `Prop` that you have no further knowledge on, there is no meaningful case analysis that you can do on it. But that's not a problem since `destruct` is not the tool you're looking for in the first place. In general, if you want to add a new hypothesis after having proved it, you should use `assert` like so:

```ml
Hypothesis (D : Type) (R : D -> D -> Prop) (a b c : D) (Hab : R a b) (Hbc : R b c).
Hypothesis Transitive : forall x y z, R x y /\ R y z -> R x z.
Goal 1+1=2. (* dummy goal for demonstration purposes *)
  assert (Hac : R a c). {
    apply Transitive with (y := b). split; [exact Hab | exact Hbc].
  }
  (* Continue your proof with the new hypothesis Hac *)
```

Or you could write the proof term yourself (this works in simple cases like this):

```
Hypothesis (D : Type) (R : D -> D -> Prop) (a b c : D) (Hab : R a b) (Hbc : R b c).
Hypothesis Transitive : forall x y z, R x y /\ R y z -> R x z.
Goal 1+1=2. (* dummy goal for demonstration purposes *)
  assert (Hac := Transitive a b c (conj Hab Hbc)).
  (* Continue your proof with the new hypothesis Hac *)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal since the conclusion of `Transitive` is `R x z`, using `destruct` fails.
So maybe what you really want to do is

```ml
assert (R a c).
apply (Transitive a b c).
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works. Now that I see it, it makes more sense. Do you know what those errors were about exactly?

Comment: `destruct` is a swiss knife. It works for every inductive definition. That's why it works for the conjunction, disjonction, boolean, natural number.... You got the message because you ask Coq  to destruct something that is not inductively defined: